# remove uitableview header gap

Tags: ios, uitableview, header

[image: UITableView example of unwanted behavior]

pictured above we have an iphone, a custom menu controller, and tableView slightly scrolled down

There is also a header on the table view, which is a grey horizontal bar, with a slightly more grey horizontal bar.

I intended for the header to stick to the very top of the view, but instead there is a gap which the scrollable section of the table view can fill when the user scrolls down, but the header remains in an unsightly position below the top of the scrollable area.

How do I fix this?

I tried setting this to a tiny value

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return .001;
}
```

but this removes the grey background in the header.

Any other suggestions? I also looked at other answers to similar questions but they were not quite addressing my problem (or didn't work).

Also, my tableView and header is made programmatically, no storyboards or xibs or interface builder involved.

**edit: guys I took a completely different approach to what I was actually trying to develop, so this problem isn't applicable to me any longer. but `self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;` was not the solution to that problem as I was already using it**

Comment: Can add code for how you create and add menu and tableView

Comment: @CQM check out the edit to my answer below

Comment: Have you tried using the 3D exploded view in the simulator to see where the gap comes from? It is useful for seeing what comes from where, esp if you change some if the colors to make it easy to see which view is which. More information on how you layout the table, create the header etc would be useful.

Comment: Did u try changing the tableView contentInset ? UIEdgeInsetsMake(-20.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

Comment: Can you add more pictures or describe the situation more? I can't tell from this question what the problem is, or what the desired outcome is.  Is the issue the 1 px space between the image and the nav bar?

Answer (score 1):

UITableViewController's views are automatically inset in iOS7 and higher so that they don't start below the navigation bar/status bar. You can controler this behavior by the setAutomaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets: method of UIViewController.

Answer (score 1):

I had something similar happen to me in a Swift project but the Property changed is the same. I found that adding this line

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
```

solved my issue and the gap disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

Did you drag in a view in `StoryBoard` to create your header view? If so, try removing the `heightForHeaderInSection:` method all together.

What is the value for `UITableViewStyle`? Try setting it to `UITableViewStyleGrouped`

Comment: No, it was created programmatically. Interface builder is not involved.

Comment: Was the UITableView created programmatically also?

Comment: UITableViewStyleGrouped removes my sticky headers, so it is not a solution. The gap phenomena is "gone" because my headers no longer stick and scroll up like the rest of the table view. It was UITableViewStylePlain